# How do I find all the elements of a pandas dataframe that are different than elements in another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes consisting mostly of columns of pandas datetime objects that represent deadlines. Each row is a project, and each column with a date in it is a deadline for that project. Both dataframes are in the same format. Here's the output of df.info() to make this a little easier to understand:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 59 entries, 0 to 58
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                 --------------  -----         
 0   Status                 59 non-null     object        
 1   ID                     44 non-null     object        
 2   Current assignment     59 non-null     object        
 3   P0                     20 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 4   P1                     29 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 5   P2                     30 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 6   IDR                    24 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 7   FDR                    26 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 8   P3                     33 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 9   PPRR                   2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 10  P4                     34 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 11  P5                     34 non-null     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](9), object(3)
memory usage: 5.7+ KB
None
```

What's the best way to determine the indices of all deadlines that are different between the two dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas.[compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)()

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Project':[1,2,3], 'DL1':['2020-09-13', '2022-11-15', '2021-01-01'], 'DL2':['2021-01-01', "2023-01-01", '2021-01-01']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Project':[1,2,3], 'DL1':['2020-09-13', '2022-01-15', '2020-01-01'], 'DL2':['2021-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2021-03-01']})


df1.compare(df2, keep_shape=True)



  Project               DL1                     DL2            
     self other        self       other        self       other
0     NaN   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1     NaN   NaN  2022-11-15  2022-01-15         NaN         NaN
2     NaN   NaN  2021-01-01  2020-01-01  2021-01-01  2021-03-01
```

You can also store this result and pull the index to use on the originals

```
diffs = df1.compare(df2, keep_shape=True).dropna(how='all')
print(diffs)

  Project               DL1                     DL2            
     self other        self       other        self       other
1     NaN   NaN  2022-11-15  2022-01-15         NaN         NaN
2     NaN   NaN  2021-01-01  2020-01-01  2021-01-01  2021-03-01


diff_list = diffs.index
print(df1.loc[df1.index.isin(diff_list)])
   Project         DL1         DL2
1        2  2022-11-15  2023-01-01
2        3  2021-01-01  2021-01-01
```

If you want to compare one column, say your P0 to P1 it becomes more complicated and I'd have to spend more time playing around with it.